# Switch between heatmap and single symbol renderer at different zoom level in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, heat-map

On a point layer in QGIS, I would like to display the points as normal single symbol points up to 1:5000 and switch to heatmap map between 1:5000 and 1:1000.

Is it possible? I can't seem to find this option in the Property > Style panel of the layer.
The problem I have at the moment is that the heatmap layer is almost invisible on a wide scale. I would like to avoid doubling layers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to duplicate the same layer in the table of content, and do the following steps:

- For the first layer, turn on `Scale dependent visibility` from `Layer Properties -> General` and set the scale of `Minimum (exclusive)` for example `1:1000,000` and `Maximum (inclusive)` `1:5000` and set the symbology to single symbol.

In the following images, I am using different scale factor because I am testing few points

[image]

[image]

- For the second layer, turn on `Scale dependent visibility` and set the
  scale of `Minimum (exclusive)` for example `1:5000` and `Maximum (inclusive)` 
  `1:1000` and set the symbology to heatmap.

[image]

[image]